# Source Sans Pro First letter is upper Chrome (wrong unicode-range)

Tags: css, google-chrome, unicode, font-face

On my Website, I use Source Sans Pro for header, without any kind of unicode-range (all my website is in French).

But, with Chrome 47, the first letter are upper :

[first letter bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLCoh.jpg)

If I move the mouse in, with the :hover style who make underline, the first letter go back in normal, and stay normal even if the mouse is out.

More strange : if I use `http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v9/ODelI1aHBYDBqgeIAH2zlC2Q8seG17bfDXYR_jUsrzg.woff2` who is for `unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;`

Instead of `http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v9/ODelI1aHBYDBqgeIAH2zlNV_2ngZ8dMf8fLgjYEouxg.woff2` who is for `unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;`

There is no problem !

For Firefox, IE 11, Edge, no problem too.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok.

Basically  I use `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`


That's mean : `@font-face` with unicode-range.

So, I copy and paste the code `@font-face`, I inverte the unicode-range, it's works ! But, it's not normal !